# Process to retrieve more than 2000 records from salesforce object.?

Tags: object, salesforce, mulesoft

I am trying to fetch records from salesforce using mulesoft application, can any one let me know, procedure to retrieve more than 2000 records from salesforce using QueryMoreAPI or any other alternate.
Thanks to you in advance.